# can't add objects of an array in another array

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays

i am trying to show selected cell checkmark when user is offline,but the array is not adding another array object,  kindly help me

1.`appDelegate.SelectedIDArray` saving selected cell
2.`buildingObject.selectedIDString` saving checked cell index coma separated

> //first i am removing all objects from array

`[appDelegate.SelectedIDArray removeAllObjects];`

> //then i am adding string  values in array(e.g 3,2,7)

```
 NSMutableArray *tempArray = (NSMutableArray*)[buildingObject.selectedIDString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

> //now adding tempArray array objects in appDelegate.SelectedIDArray

```
[appDelegate.SelectedIDArray addObjectsFromArray:tempArray];
```

> //now showing count of added object in appDelegate.SelectedIDArray

```
txtID.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%zd of 23 selected",appDelegate.SelectedIDArray.count];
```

Comment: Is `appDelegate.SelectedIDArray == nil`?

Comment: Is `appDelegate.SelectedIDArray == nil`?

Comment: yes i am removing all objects

Comment: Oh FFS.  **HAVE YOU ALLOCATED THE ARRAY?**

Comment: check my answer buddy

Comment: what do you get when you log out selectedIDString

Comment: when i nslog the selectedIDString the output will be (3,2,7),then i nslog the count of tempArray the result will be 3

Comment: And you are sure that `SelectedIDArray != nil`?  I just asking (yet again) as that's the only reason I can see why your code doesn't work.  Show us the allocation code please.

Comment: thanks to everyone who help me out my problem has been solved.

Comment: @Eyeare Given the number of people who made an effort to solve the issue for you, I think you owe them all an explanation of the issue.

Comment: there was no issue in my code,i was just forget to shared the  appDelegate

Answer (score 0):

by saying offline, you mean app is terminated, then if you didn't save your array in `NSUserDefaults` it is nil already. then you should initialize it. if this is not the case another problem may be with appDelegate:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
NSString *vals = @"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8";
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[vals componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy];
    if (!appDelegate.SelectedIDArray) {
        appDelegate.SelectedIDArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    else
    { 
        [appDelegate.SelectedIDArray removeAllObjects];
    }
    [appDelegate.SelectedIDArray addObjectsFromArray:tempArray];
    NSLog(@"%@", appDelegate.SelectedIDArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've took sample test case similar to your code:

```
NSString *str1 = @"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
NSMutableArray *tempArray = (NSMutableArray*)[str1 componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array];
[arr addObjectsFromArray:tempArray];
NSLog(@"%@",arr);
```

Its working fine for me. Make sure `appDelegate.SelectedIDArray` is NSMutableArray. Or if you want fresh array simply use

`appDelegate.SelectedIDArray = [NSMutableArray arraywitharray:tempArr];`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I hope you did not forget to alloc appDelegate.SelectedIDArray.

Comment: i had alloc in appdelegate

Answer (score -1):

Hello buddy please try this

```
NSArray *tempArray = [buildingObject.selectedIDString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

[appDelegate setSelectedIDArray:[tempArray mutableCopy]];
```

if it didnot work then possibly one of your array is empty.Please check

Comment: tempArray count is ok but SelectedIDArray count still zero

Answer (score -1):

use it, it will fix if you are using the non arc
appDelegate.SelectedIDArray = [tempArray retain];